# Redshift unload with CRLF as newline character and not LF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, newline

Can I unload from Redshift to S3 with CRLF as newline character and not LF?

I didn't find this choice

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can I ask... What process is consuming the file such that it requires a CRLF format? These days, LF is the generally-accepted format in most applications. Only Windows uses CRLF and most Windows apps can handle LF. Can you tell us about your particular use-case for requiring CRLF?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so.  CRLF is 2 characters and EOR (end or record) is a single character in text data files (I'm assuming this is what you are creating).

I expect you are looking to use the output on a Windows system.  You best bet is to define a process to "convert" the files.  A Lambda process could be set up to do this automatically if you like.